# Nth Prime via Sieve of Erastothenes as iterator

Tags: rust

I did the Nth Prime problem on exercism.io. Now I need feedback what can be done better / improved to make the most of rust. The code calculates the nth prime. I chose to provide the sieve of Eratosthenes as iterator in Rust. The code can be seen here: https://exercism.io/tracks/rust/exercises/nth-prime/solutions/22ef08ba47d0401b9ef506ee426de5cd

````rust
///implements a sieve of Eratosthenes as iterator
///https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
///The iterator skips non-primes and does the necessary
///calculations for the next.
struct Sieve {
    ///current index from where the next prime is searched
    index: usize,
    ///the sieve
    marked_numbers: Vec<bool>,
}

///largest number to be checked to be prime
///could be optimized to actually point to
///a prime number.
const MAX_SIEVE_SIZE: usize = 1_000_000;

impl Sieve {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut numbers = vec![true; MAX_SIEVE_SIZE];
        numbers[0] = false; //no prime
        numbers[1] = false; //no prime - 2 is the first prime
        Sieve {
            index: 0,
            marked_numbers: numbers,
        }
    }

    ///marks all multiples of value to be non-prime
    ///to be used by next
    fn mark_multiples(&mut self, value: usize) {
        self.marked_numbers[self.index..]
            .iter_mut()
            .step_by(value)
            .for_each(|x| *x = false);
    }
}

impl std::iter::Iterator for Sieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let slice = &self.marked_numbers[self.index + 1..];
        let position = slice.iter().position(|x| *x == true);
        match position {
            Some(x) => {
                self.index = x + self.index + 1;
                self.mark_multiples(self.index);
                Some(self.index)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

pub fn nth(n: usize) -> usize {
    let mut sieve = Sieve::new();
    sieve.nth(n).unwrap() //not nice but the API works this way
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn first_prime_is_2() {
        let mut sieve = Sieve::new();
        assert_eq!(sieve.next().unwrap(), 2);
    }

    #[test]
    fn first_few_primes_are() {
        let sieve = Sieve::new();
        let expected = [2, 3, 5, 7];
        sieve
            .zip(expected.iter())
            .for_each(|x| assert_eq!(x.0, *x.1 as usize));
    }
}
```
````

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: This could be made, such there are upper bound to the primes in the sieve.